# Use value if it exists, else assign default using the or operator

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, or-operator

I found this example in a book:

```
// Create _callbacks object, unless it already exists
var calls = this._callbacks || (this._callbacks = {});
```

I simplified it so that I did not have to use a special object scope:

```
var a = b || (b = "Hello!");
```

When b is defined, it works. When b is not defined, it does not work and throws a ReferenceError.

```
ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

Did I do anything wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When performing a property lookup like `this._callback`, if the `_callbacks` property does not exist for `this` you will get `undefined`.  However if you just do a lookup on a bare name like `b`, you will get a reference error if `b` does not exist.

One option here is to use a ternary with the `typeof` operator, which will return `"undefined"` if the operand is a variable that has not been defined.  For example:

```
var a = typeof b !== "undefined" ? b : (b = "Hello!");
```

Answer (score 4):

It should work in this form:

```
var b, a = b || (b = "Hello!", b);
//  ^ assign b
//                           ^ () and , for continuation
//                             ^ return the new value of b
//=>  result: a === b = "Hello!"
```

Comment: This will shadow any global `b` and never actually use it.
Also, I don't think the comma is necessary for such a simple assignment.

Comment: @Darkhogg I assumed OP _was_ in the global scope

Comment: @JanDvorak Then you're just creating `b`, what's the point in *conditionally* assigning a default value?

Comment: @Tobias it's a comma expression. It evaluates all operands and returns the last one

Comment: This is really interesting. Could you please explain why it works? The "a" seems to be a game changer.

Comment: Okay, I got it. You define a **and** b so that b will not cause a ReferenceError anymore when being involved in the expression without having been defined before.

Comment: @Darkhogg: the comma *is* necessary in this construction.